# How can I print a parent element of my xml file

Tags: python, lxml

So here is my xml file:

```
<pdv id="78000016" latitude="4879100" longitude="211400">
    <adress>adress_info</adress>
    <city>Versailles</city>
</pdv>
```

And here is my python code:

```
for example in tree.xpath(f"pdv[city='Paris']/state"):
    ville = example.text
```

So I have a big amount of that part of XML info's and what I want is to get the latitude of each `pdv` where the <city> is Paris.

To allow me to get each `pdv` with Paris as `city` I use this:

```
[city='Paris']
```

But my issue is that I can't figure how to get the latitude every time a `pdv` with Paris as `city` is fund.

Comment: It is unclear what the problem is. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Elements have a `.getparent()` method that will return the parent element. Is that what you're looking for?